# How to get a string from unicode data returned from sql query (python,sql,wxpython)

Tags: python, sqlite, wxpython

What I'm trying to do is create a list of pure strings from a

```
cur.fetchall()
```

query.

I've read a few similar type answers on Stack and they don't work. I know it's only unicode and if you print the data it was print the str but I'm using this query to populate a wx.choice

i've used a list comprehension to append the str to a new list and that doesn't work either. I'm also trying to take the string out of the tuple.

How do I get a pure string list

```
['one','two','three']
```

from a returned query

```
[(u'one'),(u'one'),(u'three)]
```

so i can use a wx.choice the way I'm sure it was meant to be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[str(u) for u in [(u'one'),(u'one'),(u'three')]]
```

So what we do is using the function `str` on every element to get the desired result of `['one','two','three']` .

Comment: the problem here is, the query comes back with different values. So I'm assigning the query to a variable. Do I just plug in the variable name where u start the list?

Comment: altered this formula slightly because it didn't work but added a while loop that converted anything not type(str) and it worked perfectly...maybe more code than I needed but atleast worked.

Comment: This won't work for any characters in the unicode sting outusde of ascii(128), try it with this: `[(u"øne",), (u"†wo",), (u"th®ee",)]`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of wx are you using? (`wx.version()`). `wx.choice` should accept unicode input.

The issue might be that sql returns a list of tuples, and you may be trying to pass tuples to the widget. Try accessing the string inside with an index `[0]`

```
[u[0] for u in [(u'one',),(u'one',),(u'three',)]`
```